# ExtJS 6 tabindex broken

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I have a problem with form tabIndex values:
Blue numbers are tabIndex values set for each field.
Red numbers is how actual field focus jumps from field to field when I press tab key on keyboard.

[image: Field tabindex vs. field focus switching]

My tabIndex values for all form fields are set to -1. I even set tabIndex on toolbar buttons to -1. Publish field has tabIndex set to 1, Media field has tabIndex set to 2, Rubric field has tabIndex set to 3 and finally Genre field has tabIndex set to 4.

If I focus Published field and start pressing Tab key the focus jumps from Publish field to first button in toolbar, then it jumps to Media field, next it jumps to Genre field and then to Rubric field.

Any idea to fix this would be appreciated.

Regards

Armando

Comment: May you provide https://fiddle.sencha.com/ sample which will reproduce the bug?

Comment: I will try and create one ... will take me some time to implement since my view is enormous